# having trouble connecting to wireless on FreeBSD 11 on RasPi 2

Tags: wifi, freebsd, raspberry-pi

I have everything setup.  I can see the USB network card in dmesg.  But it won't associate with AP/SSID.  It shows everything else but the ssid won't work.  I'm not sure if the wifi card will work....

This is a Netopia USB Wireless-N card.  dmesg says its a RealTek 2573 chipset.

dmesg:

```
rum0: <Ralink 802.11 bg WLAN, class 0/0, rev 2.00/0.01, addr 6> on usbus0
rum0: MAC/BBP RT2573 (rev 0x2573a), RF RT2528
wlan0: Ethernet address: 00:d0:41:be:c0:e4
```

ifconfig:

```
ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    ether 00:d0:41:be:c0:e4
    groups: wlan
    ssid "" channel 3 (2422 MHz 11g)
    regdomain FCC country US authmode OPEN privacy OFF txpower 30 bmiss 7
    scanvalid 60 bgscan bgscanintvl 300 bgscanidle 250 roam:rssi 7
    roam:rate 5 protmode CTS wme bintval 0
    media: IEEE 802.11 Wireless Ethernet autoselect (autoselect)
    status: no carrier
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>

cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
network={
    ssid="freebsd"
    psk=password
}
```

/var/log/messages:

```
cat /var/log/messages|egrep "wlan0|rum0"
Oct 10 00:53:20 asm-console01 kernel: wlan0: link state changed to UP
Oct 10 00:54:39 asm-console01 kernel: wlan0: link state changed to DOWN
Oct 10 01:06:02 asm-console01 kernel: rum0: <Ralink 802.11 bg WLAN, class     0/0, rev 2.00/0.01, addr 6> on usbus0
Oct 10 01:06:02 asm-console01 kernel: rum0: MAC/BBP RT2573 (rev 0x2573a), RF RT2528
Oct 10 01:06:02 asm-console01 kernel: wlan0: Ethernet address: 00:d0:41:be:c0:e4
```

/etc/rc.conf:

```
wlan_load="YES"
wlan_ccmp_load="YES"
wlan_tkip_load="YES"
wlans_rum0="wlan0"
ifconfig_wlan0="asm inet 10.150.1.41 netmask 255.255.255.0"
dhcpd_enable="YES"
dhcpd_flags="-q"
dhcpd_conf="/usr/local/etc/dhcpd.conf"
dhcpd_ifaces="ue0"
dhcpd_withumask="022"
ser2net_enable="YES"
wpa_supplicant_enable="YES"
```

/boot/loader.conf:

```
cat /boot/loader.conf
boot_multicons="YES"
boot_serial="YES"
comconsole="19200"

legal.realtek.license_ack=1
if_rum_load="YES"
rt2573_load="YES"
wlan_amrr_load="YES"
#wlan_wep_load="YES"
wlan_tkip_load="YES"
wlan_ccmp_load="YES"
uplcom_load="YES"
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `/boot/loader.conf` by adding the following lines:

```
if_rum_load="YES"
wlan_ccmp_load="YES"
wlan_tkip_load="YES"
wlan_xauth_load="YES"
```

Edit your `etc/rc.conf` , add the following lines:

```
wlans_rum0="wlan0"
```

Edit the `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` , as follow:

```
network={
ssid="your_ssid"
psk="your_password"
}
```

Create the network :

```
ifconfig wlan create wlandev rum0
```

**Static Ip**

To configure a static IP you should remove the DHCP entry from the  `/etc/rc.conf`  then run the following command:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
ifconfig wlan0 inet 10.150.1.41 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add default your_default_router
echo "nameserver your_DNS_server" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

**DHCP**

To get an IP through DHCP you should add `ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"` to your `/etc/rc.conf` file:

```
echo 'ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"' >> /etc/rc.conf
```